# Kindle vs Books and ecofriendliness

Tags: environment

I was in a conversation with a friend trying to convince her to switch to kindle, so she said that the cost and plastic material and eco footprint of kindle is higher then all the EBooks she could possibly read.  [While others have made the case that eReaders are more ecofriendly](http://www.guardian.co.uk/books/booksblog/2010/mar/09/ecological-ebooks).

So, which one is true? What is the ecological cost of the kindle? How green is it? How many Ebooks do I need to read on it to justify the eco cost of buying it?

I just want to know how valid my friend's argument is?

Thanks much for feedback :)

Comment: Welcome to Skeptics. According to the FAQ, this site is for researching the evidence behind the claims you hear or read. This question doesn't appear to have any doubtful claims to investigate. Please edit it if you feel otherwise.

Comment: @Jose: you could always rephrase it to say something about how [united airlines switched to paperless navigation charts](http://www.united.com/press/detail/0,7056,69128,00.html) and ask what the real offset really is, and answers could refer to [production-related emissions and energy use](http://images.apple.com/environment/reports/docs/iPad_Environmental_Report.pdf)...

Comment: @josek, i made it more skeptical, thanks for guidelines

Comment: Kindles aren't just for books; they're also good for .pdf files as well.  I used my Kindle to avoid having 1000+ pages of printed material for 4 classes each college semester.

Comment: Related: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/5930/how-much-are-united-airlines-reducing-their-carbon-emissions-by-giving-pilots-ipa

Comment: You must also consider any books you would normally bring with you on a flight, car ride etc.  This weight adds to the energy costs of moving you from point a to b.  If you eliminate most of your paper traffic you can save quite a bit of energy.  But the convience factor did it for me.  I could never cart around all of my refernece material but I love my nook for doing it for me.

Comment: I'm helping offset the ecofriendliness you e-reader users are having.  I bought one, hated it, went back to buying paper, so now it's sitting on a shelf unused, just mocking me with the claims that it would save me money and help me be more eco-friendly.  :-)

Comment: late but still - how often are books thrown away? How often are e-readers thrown away? Given the general advance of technology I imagine that in the coming decades the e-waste contribution of e-readers will start to have an effect on the answers to this question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I just did an edit to your question, and realized that the link I put in there has the answers you were looking for.  They are not definitive, because people use books and ebook readers differently form individual to individual, and the technology is new so we haven't collected all the data yet.  However, from [a blog entry on The Guardian](http://www.guardian.co.uk/books/booksblog/2010/mar/09/ecological-ebooks) (so take it for what it's worth)

> I've only managed to find one report – on the Kindle (by [The Cleantech Group](http://www.cleantech.com/news/4867/cleantech-group-finds-positive-envi)) – but it backs up suggestions that so long as e-readers are used as book replacements rather than supplements, they soon start to pay back in carbon terms. The report states that a book uses up "approximately 7.46 kilograms of CO2 over its lifetime" and that the Kindle produces "roughly 168 kg" during its lifecycle, making it "a clear winner against the potential savings: 1,074 kg of CO2 if replacing three books a month for four years; and up to 26,098 kg of CO2 when used to the fullest capacity of the Kindle."

[For a full report from The Cleantech Group, here is a link to a PDF document](http://www.publicradio.org/columns/marketplace/sustainability-answers/The%20environmental%20impact%20of%20the%20Amazon%20Kindle.pdf).  The author of the blog goes on to say

> Nevertheless, I'm part-way convinced. There are clear advantages to using e-readers in schools and academe. At home, I'm less sure – especially when you factor in side-issues such as the toxicity of the heavy metals used in ebook readers and their batteries. I also hesitate because the devices are so new we still know little about how they're used.
>
> Here, I'm hoping an informal survey here might shed more light. So tell me: if you own an e-reader, how often do you use it? (Have you for instance topped off the 22.5 books The Cleantech Group require to break even with traditional books in carbon terms?)

So basically, if you put 23 books on the Kindle, you are ahead of the game according to this.

There are some other things to consider too.  [For instance](http://www.teleread.com/robert-nagle/apple-amazon-rated-at-bottom-of-climate-change-scorecard-and-what-about-ebooks/)

> The current book ordering system encourages bookstores to order more books than they can reasonably sell. That increases the number of published copies and consequently the number of returns (and the amount of shipping costs).

[Additionally](http://www.grist.org/article/in-a-bind)

> A MS candidate named Greg Kozak [pitted textbooks against e-book devices](http://css.snre.umich.edu/css_doc/CSS03-04.pdf) [PDF] in 2003. He found that paper production, electricity of printing operations, and personal transportation were the main factors affecting the book footprint, while electricity was the main issue for e-readers; and that books were responsible for four times the greenhouse emissions as e-readers.

[Self Publishing Review states](http://www.selfpublishingreview.com/blog/2009/02/11/ebooks-and-environmental-impact/)

> On Salon, there’s a highly technical summary of [the amount of energy it takes to read on a computer vs. printing out an article to read it](http://www.salon.com/news/environment/ask_pablo/2008/09/08/printers/). The verdict: “The contrast is quite convincing, one-tenth of a pound of greenhouse gas emissions from reading the document on the computer, versus almost one-quarter of a pound of greenhouse gas emissions for printing it out!”

Or more specifically to the Kindle

> Another article lays out the [environmental impact of reading a newspaper](http://fatknowledge.blogspot.com/2008/08/e-books-vs-newspapers.html) on a reader and reading the New York Times on an ebook. Their conclusion: “Reading the physical version of the NY Times for a year uses 7,300 MJ of energy and emits 700 kg of co2. Reading it on a Kindle uses 100 MJ of energy and emits 10 kg of co2.”

Hope that helps.

Comment: Here's a full PDF of the Cleantech report http://www.publicradio.org/columns/marketplace/sustainability-answers/The%20environmental%20impact%20of%20the%20Amazon%20Kindle.pdf

Comment: "paper production, electricity of printing operations, and personal transportation were the main factors affecting the book footprint, while electricity was the main issue for e-readers" This suggests the number of times you read each book (zero incremental cost for paper, as much electricity again for Kindles) is a factor.

Comment: @Oddthinking that is true.  Although I bet that quantifying that would be neigh impossible...

Comment: This "study" illustrates the main problem with CO2 focus.  They behave as if CO2 is the only pollutant produced in either process and ignore all others.  CO2 is not the only pollutant dangerous to the environment and low CO2 may not equal eco-friendly.

Comment: @Russell the Guardian article mentions `especially when you factor in side-issues such as the toxicity of the heavy metals used in ebook readers and their batteries.` so that is not an only CO2 measure for what it's worth.